# PHP Getting out of memory

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, memory-management

I am trying to insert data from postgres database into mysql database. There are about `100000` records that I need to import. However Iam always getting out of memory issue.

`Out of memory (allocated 1705508864) (tried to allocate 222764 bytes)`

I am using Laravel 5 to do this, here is code:

```
// to avoid memory limit or time out issue
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
ini_set('max_input_time', '-1');
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');
set_time_limit(0);

// this speeds up things a bit
DB::disableQueryLog();

$importableModels = [
    // array of table names
];

$failedChunks = 0;

foreach ($importableModels as $postGresModel => $mysqlModel) {

    $total = $postGresModel::count();
    $chunkSize = getChunkSize($total);

    // customize chunk size in case of certain tables to avoid too many place holders error
    if ($postGresModel === 'ApplicationFormsPostgres') {
        $chunkSize = 300;
    }

    $class = 'App\\Models\\' . $mysqlModel;
    $object = new $class;

    // trucate prev data //
    Eloquent::unguard();
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');
    $object->truncate();
    DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');
    Eloquent::reguard();

    $postGresModel::chunk($chunkSize, function ($chunk) use ($postGresModel, $mysqlModel, $failedChunks, $object) {

        // make any adjustments
        $fixedChunk = $chunk->map(function ($item, $key) use ($postGresModel) {

            $appendableAttributes = $postGresModel::APPEND_FIELDS;
            $attributes = $item->getAttributes();

            // replace null/no values with empty string
            foreach ($attributes as $key => $attribute) {
                if ($attribute === null) {
                    $attributes[$key] = '';
                }
            }

            // add customized attributes and values
            foreach ($appendableAttributes as $appendField) {
                if ($appendField === 'ssn') {
                    $value = $attributes['number'];
                    $attributes[$appendField] = substr($value, 0, 4);
                } else {
                    $attributes[$appendField] = '';
                }

            }

            return $attributes;
        });

        // insert chunk of data in db now
        if (!$object->insert($fixedChunk->toArray())) {
            $failedChunks++;
        }

    });    
}
```

Memory issue comes when about `80000` rows are inserted not before that.

I suspect something is wrong with collection `map` function or loops inside the map function. I have even tried setting memory setting and time limit settings to unlimited but to no avail. May be I need to use reference variables or something but I am not sure how.

**Can any optimizations be made in above code to reduce memory usage?**

**Or how do I efficiently import large data from large PostgreSQL database to MySQL through code ?**

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong here or why whole memory gets consumed up ?

PS: I am doing this on local development machine which has 4GB ram (Windows 8). PHP version: 5.6.16

Comment: How much memory have you allowed PHP to use? (This can be changed in `php.ini`). Sorry, ignore this :p I didn't see the start of your code.

Comment: @PXgamer: Unlimited as can be seen on first line `ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');` I also tried setting to other values such as `ini_set('memory_limit', '1024MB');` or greater but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried to reduced the chunk size?

Comment: @Sarcoma: yes tried setting at to lesser value but strangely it again went out of memory on about `80000` records

Comment: Shot in the dark. `ini_set` only prevents PHP from requesting more memory from the machine... Is there a ulimit on the process from the OS?

Comment: @taylorcressy: nope there is no limit and I don't know why it is not using more memory as `1705508864` bytes are being allocated meaning `1705MB/1.7GB`. May be something is wrong with code but I don't find optimization points in the code :(

Comment: Have you tried gc_collect_cycles(); after you insert your chunk.

Comment: @AhmetGunes: It gave me value of `1085`

Comment: seems that you have a memory leak somewhere. my question is how can you have this: $postGresModel::count(); I would like to see how is your $importableModels array.

Comment: @ElzoValugi: `$postGresModel` is instance of laravel Eloquent model and `count` comes as part of that as well.

Comment: what I found strange is that they call a function over a key from an array, which should be a basic type: an integer or a string

Comment: @ElzoValugi: Any idea on improvement in code to consume less memory ?

Comment: I said I suspect a memory leak, because having 8000 entries in an array should not be a problem in itself. But somewhere in the loop things are added to the memory and not properly garbaged. I would try to use a profiler to detect the memory leak. If there is none or I just want to get the job done and move on, then I would go for splitting the 8000 in batches of  500 or 1000, unset all variables in between the batches and adjust the batch value until memory usage is within the limits.

Comment: @dev02 try doing `unset($object, $chunk);` right after insert IF statement.

Comment: What if you wrote code that iterated the PostgreSQL table and created MySQL-compliant INSERT statements to a text file, and then loaded the text file (even if you had to break up the text file into chunks or create a PHP script to fire each INSERT statement manually)?

Comment: Maybe comes this error from your mysql database? How about max_allowed_packet, query cache limit, query_cache_size? Check the database logs.

Comment: @Basti: Tried that, it isn't the issue.

Comment: Is anything a "32-bit" application?  1.7G is about where such applications keel over.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE` -- it would be interesting to see what datatypes are involved.

Comment: Workbench will probably import all of Postgres for you.

Comment: Is it correct to have `return $attributes;` not in a `function`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely, you've got a memory leak somewhere. I guess somewhere within `$chunk->map()`, or `$object->insert($fixedChunk->toArray())`. We can only guess, because the implementation is hidden.

However, I would use [generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php) as much as possible. The code might look something like the following:

```php
function getAllItems() {
  $step = 2000;

  for ($offset = 0 ;; $offset += $step) {
    $q = "SELECT * FROM items_table LIMIT $offset, $step";

    if (! $items = Db::fetchAll($q)) {
      break;
    }

    foreach ($items as $i) {
      yield $i;
    }
  }
}

foreach (getAllItems() as $item) {
  import_item($item);
}
```

I dare to say that with generators you'll be able to import practically any amount of data from one database to another.

Comment: Thanks for generator + step thing. I modified code a bit to insert data in chunks but thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you could change the 'memory_limit'.  But that only works today, not tomorrow, when you will need even more memory.

Plan A:

Instead, write a little more code...  Chunk up the data into, say, 1000 rows at a time.  Build a single `INSERT` statement with all the rows in it.  Execute it in a transaction by itself.

Plan B:

Build a CSV file of all the rows, then use `LOAD DATA INFILE` to do the mass insert.

In either Plan, avoid loading all the rows into RAM at once.  There is a *lot* of overhead for scalars and arrays in PHP.

Comment: I am already chunking data using `chunk` method of eloquent as can be seen in code, can't chunk into more than 500 to avoid too many parameters error and csv is not option, need to do via code. There is something wrong in code where memory gets leaked which needs to be identified may be. thanks

Answer (score 1):

1.- Try commenting the content of data processing logic to check if the memory leak is within this code:

```
$postGresModel::chunk($chunkSize, function ($chunk) use ($postGresModel, $mysqlModel, $failedChunks, $object) {

        // make any adjustments
        $fixedChunk = $chunk->map(function ($item, $key) use ($postGresModel) {

              ///Nothing to do 
       }
}
```

2.- If you'll get the same error, memory leak could be produced by the mysql driver (PDO?) when trying to dump all rows from query result, buffering all rows in memory.

As in [PostgreSQL unbuffered queries and PHP (cursors)](https://codepoets.co.uk/2014/postgresql-unbuffered-queries/#more-936) you could change the behavior of hoy postgreSql fetch rows using a cursor:

```
$curSql = "DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * FROM big_table";
$con = new PDO("pgsql:host=dbhost dbname=database", "user", "pass");
$con->beginTransaction(); // cursors require a transaction.
$stmt = $con->prepare($curSql);
$stmt->execute();

$innerStatement = $con->prepare("FETCH 1 FROM cursor1");

while($innerStatement->execute() && $row = $innerStatement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['field'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you grab your PostgreSQL data, try to `LIMIT` the size of what gets returned (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/queries-limit.html) to something reasonable and then iterate.

Say for instance you took 20000 rows at a time, you would do 'SELECT .. BLAH .. LIMIT 20000 OFFSET 0', then next iteration would be 'SELECT .. BLAH .. LIMIT 20000 OFFSET 20000', (the OFFSET being 20000 * your loop counter).

Process these batches until you have no rows left.

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions.

- You instantiate a new `$object` object at each loop. Depending on the actual structure of the `MySqlModel` and the number of items it can definitely use a lot of memory (also because of GC not yet working, see second suggestion). Set it to NULL at the end of each loop, i.e.

`$object = NULL;`

- If execution time is not an issue, insert a little delay between each loop. This allows PHP garbage collector to do some work and free up unused resources.

Answer (score 0):

`map` will return a new instance of your collection. GC will clean that up too late.

Try replacing

```
$chunk = $chunk->map(function...
```

with

```
$newchunk = $chunk->map(function...
```

and of course use the new chunk when inserting, `$object->insert($newchunk->toArray())`. You can use `transform` instead of `map` too.

GC should collect it now, but you can add an `unset($newchunk);` after the insert to make sure. An `unset($object);` in the second to last line of your code wouldn't hurt either.

Comment: Have you tried unset? And I had another idea: can you try replacing the $key-variable in `foreach` with e.g. $key1? `foreach ($attributes as $key1 => $attribute) { if ($attribute === null) { $attributes[$key1] = ''; } }`? Don't know if it would cause a memory leak, but feels fishy and might accumulate.